# Javascript changing input field diables button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">                                            
    <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
       <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
       <span>
       <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn>
        <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email:
    </button></a>
   </div>
```

How do i make it so that if theres any changes made to the **id_planner_step_email_address** input field the **send_email_btn** gets disabled

Comment: Why not make it readonly?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show the JS code?

Comment: Hey did you sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it readonly?

Anyway - I fixed your invalid HTML -no need to wrap a button in an anchor and you had a lose span there

I allow changing if they change back

jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#send_email_btn").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#id_planner_step_email_address").on("input", function() {
    $("#send_email_btn").prop("disabled", this.value!=this.defaultValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
  <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
  <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn" disabled="disabled">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email: </button>
</div>
```

Plain JS

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("send_email_btn").disabled=false;
  document.getElementById("id_planner_step_email_address").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.getElementById("send_email_btn").disabled=this.value!=this.defaultValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
  <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
  <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn" disabled="disabled">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email: </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all fix your invalid HTML, missing some of the ending quotes `"`.Then you can try this way with inline [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) event or [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) on text element,

**With inline** using`oninput`:

```js
function disableButton() {
  document.getElementById("send_email_btn").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
  <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" oninput="disableButton()" />
  <span>
       <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email:
    </button></a>
   </div>
```

**Without inline** using `input`:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('id_planner_step_email_address').addEventListener('input', function() {
    document.getElementById("send_email_btn").disabled = true;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
  <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
  <span>
       <a href=""><button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email:
    </button></a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Not super elegant - inline and all. Also if someone pastes something, the field has to be blurred to trigger

Comment: Yes you're ri8 sir, I think `oninput` event will do the trick. What you say?

Comment: better but still inline

Comment: But it’s pretty similar to others now

Answer (score 0):

Here the code allows the disabled button to back to enable if the email gets back to its original address.

```js
var currentEmail = $("#id_planner_step_email_address").val();
$(function() {

  $("#id_planner_step_email_address").on("input", function() {
    if (currentEmail != $(this).val()) {
      $("#send_email_btn").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $("#send_email_btn").prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
  <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
  <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email: </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a script tag to the end of your body...and note that your `<span>` tag is not closed.

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">                                            
    <label for="id_planner_step_email_address">To:</label>
    <input type="email" name="planner_step_email_address" value="a@sp.edu.sg" maxlength="254" required id="id_planner_step_email_address" />
    <span>
        <a href="">
            <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="send_email_btn">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i> Send Email:
            </button>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector('#id_planner_step_email_address');
    const button = document.querySelector('#send_email_btn');  
    input.addEventListener('change', button.disabled = true);  
</script>
```